# C++ polymorphic call without explicit pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism

If I have base class:

```
struct Base
{
  void foo()
  {
    bar();
  }

  virtual void bar() 
  {
  }
};
```

And derived class:

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
  void bar()
  {
    cerr << "Derived here\n";
  } 
};
```

It is happen that when write this code:

```
Derived d;
d.foo();
```

I will see printing "Derived here" - since `Derived::bar` was called. But I did not call via pointer to base, but polymorphism working here. Why? Is it because the call to `bar` in `Base::foo` is implicitly actually to `this->bar()` and `bar` is finding in vtable of class?

Comment: You were half right.  It isn't an explicit pointer but it does look in the vtable for the first entry for that function.  Since the derived class supplied a new entry for that function you are calling the derived function.  Polymorphism works regardless of pointers - it's just all the examples use pointers to show how easy it is to decouple using polymorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is precisely correct (although bear in mind that the C++ standard says nothing about vtables).

Comment: you mention C++ standard - but it says that this code should work like this, no? or this undefined bahaviur?

Comment: @zaharpopov: It *is* indeed defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because the call to bar in Base::foo is implicitly actually to this->bar() and bar is finding in vtable of class?

The `d.foo()` call actually does `(&d)->foo()`, so `foo()` receives a `this` pointer, looks up the vtable, and finds the correct `bar()` implementation.

In other words, to `foo()`, it doesn't matter whether it was called via a pointer or not. It always gets a `this` pointer and works the same way regardless.

Comment: `d_ptr->foo()` actually does `(*d_ptr).foo()`, not the other way around. The `this` pointer in assembly is simply a `lea eax,d` (load effective address, `&d` in C/C++ terms).

Answer (score 0):

You were half right. It isn't an explicit pointer but it does look in the vtable for the first entry for that function. Since the derived class supplied a new entry for that function you are calling the derived function. Polymorphism works regardless of pointers - it's just all the examples use pointers to show how easy it is to decouple using polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

1) why are you defining methods in structs?

2) yep, polymorphism is what gets you to call `Derived::foo()` rather than `Base::foo()` because you declared it virtual. Indeed, this allowed the code to find the correct method in the vtable of the class (or whichever pointer table structure the compiler creates for you to keep track of the polymorphic methods.)

Comment: because i'm lazy adding public specifiers :)

Comment: @luis:  if (most) everything is public, then why not use a struct?

Comment: @Oli: I know there is nothing wrong (syntactically) with adding methods to structs. The question here was more like *what is "his" intention behind it?* There are no hard rules where to do so, but in general, one wants to use structs where there is state, but not behavior (though you might want to attach methods to it as a convenience as opposed to intentionally implementing behavior.)

Comment: @John - good question. I would use a struct when everything is public, but then, at least by convention, I'd assume that there is no state to protect, no complex invariants to really worry about (or that are difficult to recover from when they get violated.) The only diff between a struct (with methods) and a class is the default visibility, more than one way to build the same complex thing without any clear rules. I know it is pretty subjective of me, but that C++ feature has always given me the creeps :)

Comment: con't not to mention the differences in default constructor initialization between structs and classes. But now I'm deviating :)

Comment: There is no difference in default constructor initialization between classes defined with keyword `struct` and classes defined with keyword `class`. Some people try to use `struct` if and only if their class is POD, but they generally mess it up in one direction or the other (or both), since the compiler doesn't help them.

Comment: By bad, I meant to say "default initialization" as opposed to "default constructor initialization". C++ guarantees a struct to be zero-initialized by default, but makes no such guarantees with a class.

Comment: That's how I'd use a struct, as a POD. Certainly the compiler doesn't help (and I always thought that's a bizarre design choice in C++ to have structs and classes so similar in semantic equivalence.) It is unfortunate because something that the compiler could have done was left up in the air by whatever convention people chose to implement (and sometimes poorly follow). When people fail (because the compiler doesn't help them), they are doing it wrong. If that their intention, they should treat structs as they would be in C (avoiding all the member method and struct inheritance malarkey.)

Comment: C++ does not guarantee *anything* different about initialization of classes defined with `struct` vs. `class`. It is not true that structs are guaranteed to be zero-initialized. It's not even true that PODs are guaranteed to be zero-initialized. If X is a POD struct and you do `X x;`, then the members of `x` have indeterminate initial values.

Comment: The ways people mess up using `struct` to mean POD is for example to put a `std::string` in a struct (accidentally making it non-POD), or to forget to define a constructor in a class that has a few non-virtual member functions (accidentally making it POD, although most classes will have private members, which avoids this accident). If you need the two to be labelled it seems *far* better to me to use either a naming convention, or use comments in the definitions of POD-classes saying they are POD, than to invent a meaning for `struct` which doesn't exist in the language.

Comment: "but in general, one wants to use structs where there is state, but not behavior", I disagree. I'm generally using structs where I need a quick scratch class. Like, visitors for some quick matter or policies for a single function calls etc. They may well have state.

Comment: @Steve - *"it seems far better to me to use either a naming convention, or use comments in the definitions of POD-classes saying they are POD, than to invent a meaning for struct which doesn't exist in the language."* - by using a naming convention and comments you are indeed **inventing** a meaning for it that is not supported by the language. In fact, as you and I say in different words, C++ doesn't provide that much of a semantic difference between a class and a struct.

Comment: @Steve - con't. When a language is ambiguous about something - as with the nature/intention of a struct in **C++** (unlike class which is understood) - the safest think is to take a Occam's Razor'ish approach and default to the simplest one (or one with an older historical precedence.) To me (I know, *subjective*), this will lead me to apply the historical C-based meaning of a struct (as a POD, and also equivalent to "records" in other languages) as opposed to a quasi-equivalent to a class with an equivalence open to anyone's interpretation and usage enforced by non-universal convention only.

Comment: @Johannes - You disagree, because that's how **you** interpret struct usage. Nothing wrong with it, but what is the justification of having something in a language that kinda-like are the same, but not so, unenforceable by the compiler? Since C++ has ***never*** provided syntactically-enforceable rules on how/when to use them, the simplest thing (and in almost any other language of the Algol family with support for records and udt's) is to apply a C interpretation and usage to structs. I admit it's just an opinion, one I believe is justifiable for practical, simplistic and historical reasons.

Comment: The point is that C++ needs to have `struct` for compatibility with C, and chose to have `class` because that's a much more OOP-evocative name. I agree that it's bad to have things which are kind-a the same but not enforced by the compiler, which is exactly why I *don't* join you in this invented meaning that structs should be POD and non-struct classes should be non-POD. You're the one *making* them kind-a the same but not enforced. If we use them solely according to what default accessibility we want, we avoid this problem, since the compiler and I agree on the differences.

Comment: Although note that even using them for convenience has a potential problem, in that MSVC mangles names differently according to which keyword you use, so forward declarations need to agree. I don't think it's entirely clear whether the standard backs this behavior or not, and it doesn't affect litb's usage of one-shot functors because in any case they wouldn't be forward-declared and used in other translation units, but I think the cautious thing is either to use `struct` always and never `class`, or else `struct` solely in "extern C" interfaces, and `class` where possible.