# C++ inheritance and virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Reading through a text book, I have come away with the impression that overriding virtual functions only works when using a pointer or reference to the object.  The book demonstrates the creation of a pointer of the base class type pointed to an object the derived class type, and uses that to demonstrate a virtual function override.

However, I've now come across the following.  Not a pointer in sight, and I was expecting that making function1 virtual would not make a difference, but it does.  I'm clearly missing something here and would appreciate an explanation as to what it is.  Sorry if my explanation isn't clear; also I expect this has been asked before, but was unable to come up with what to search on.

```
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
public:
    void function1(); // virtual or not?
    void function2();
};

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    void function1();
};

int main()
{
    ClassA objA;
    ClassB objB;

    objA.function1();
    cout << "\n";
    objA.function2();
    cout << "\n";
    objB.function1();
    cout << "\n";
    objB.function2(); // Fourth call
    cout << "\n";
}

void ClassA::function1() { cout << "ClassA::function1\n"; }

void ClassA::function2()
{
    cout << "ClassA::function2\n";
    function1(); // For the fourth call ClassA::function1()
                    // is called if ClassA::function1() is not virtual
                    // but ClassB:function1() is called if it is.  Why? 
}

void ClassB::function1() { cout << "ClassB::function1\n"; }
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: `// virtual or not?` - obviously not, as it is not declared as `virtual`.

Comment: Sorry.  I haven't explained myself clearly.  I was using the comments in the code to ask the question.  If A:function1 is as above (i.e. not virtual), this is the result of running to code:

 ClassA::function1

 ClassA::function2
 ClassA::function1

 ClassB::function1

 ClassA::function2
 ClassA::function1

 Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: If I change it to be virtual, I get this:

 ClassA::function1

 ClassA::function2
 ClassA::function1

 ClassB::function1

 ClassA::function2
 ClassB::function1

 Press any key to continue . . .
 
So making the function virtual does make a difference, and implements polymorphism (I believe).  My point is that I wasn't expecting it to, and I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of virtual without explicit pointers :

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void f1()
        {
            cout << "A::f1()" << endl;
        }

        void f2()
        {
            f1();
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        void f1() override
        {
            cout << "B::f1()" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.f2();
    b.f2();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Searching on "virtual without explicit pointers" led me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276635/c-virtual-function-call-without-pointer-or-reference.  That's what I was missing: the this pointer.  (doh).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903443/c-polymorphic-call-without-explicit-pointer

Answer (score 1):

It's not a virtual function as it is not marked as one. It's simply a public function **accessible** from a derived class / object. Your code is not exhibiting polymorphic behavior either. That being said none of your functions are [virtual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) nor [overriding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). Trivial example for polymorphic installation would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ClassA {
public:
    virtual void function1() { // now virtual
        std::cout << "ClassA::function1\n";
    }
};

class ClassB : public ClassA {
public:
    void function1() override {
        std::cout << "ClassB::function1\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<ClassA> p = std::make_unique<ClassB>();
    p->function1(); // now calls class B function, overrides class A behavior
}
```

or through references:

```
int main() {
    ClassB objB;
    ClassA& ro = objB;
    ro.function1(); // now calls class B function, overrides class A behavior
}
```

There is little benefit in marking functions as `virtual` and `override` if you are not utilizing polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: Sorry.  I haven't explained myself clearly.  I was using the comments in the code to ask the question.  If A:function1 is as above (i.e. not virtual), this is the result of running to code:

Answer (score 0):

function1 is not virtual, obj2 calls the classB function1 because it is a clasB object, the compiler first looks at the most-derived type for a function, then the leftmost base (and on through the bases of that base), and then the next base in multiple inheritance situations. If you took a classA * to obj2 and called function1 it would call the classA function1.